# LWJGL 2D texture mapping offscreen

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am trying to map a 2D image to a quad as a background image. The image is drawn at the center of the screen so it ends up only covering the top right quater with the rest going offscreen. Is there anyway I can translate or change the TexCoord so it wil draw from the bottom left? Below is the code I am using.

```
        background.bind();          
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
             GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
             GL11.glVertex2i(0,0);
             GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
             GL11.glVertex2i(0,600);
             GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
             GL11.glVertex2i(800,600);
             GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
             GL11.glVertex2i(800,0);
        GL11.glEnd();
```

Comment: Is that honestly the best question title you can think of for this?

Comment: I hope this will make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with textures; if you took your texture away, it would render exactly the same as it does now.

OpenGL does not naturally take vertices in window coordinates. In order to allow it to do so, you generally need to set up an orthographic projection matrix of some form, typically with `glOrtho`. This would look something like:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

//Render stuff in window coordinates here.

glPopMatrix();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();
```

The matrix pushing and popping ensures that the prior matrix is preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am now using glOrtho as you suggest above, the image is now fitting the screen as I indented however it is flipped hoziontally, is there an order to my code above that I could change to fix how the image is mapped?

Comment: I changed the order and it is flipped correctly, thanks for the help.